How to build gradle project with xtend plugin applied
I am trying to build the gradle project by applying the xtend plugin. But build is getting failed with some errors.
Can someone please suggest me with how to apply xtend plugin and build the entire project with out having any errors.
Below is the sample script i used:
plugins {
  id "org.xtext.xtend"  version "2.0.6"
  id 'org.xtext.builder' version '2.0.6'
  id 'java'
}
repositories {
            mavenCentral()
        }

        dependencies {
            implementation 'org.eclipse.xtend:org.eclipse.xtend.lib:2.17.1'
            xtextLanguages 'org.eclipse.xtend:org.eclipse.xtend.core:2.17.1'
        }

sourceSets {
  main.java.srcDirs = ['src','xtend-gen']
  main.xtend.srcDirs = ['src/main/xtend','xtend-gen']
  main.xtendOutputDir = 'xtend-gen'
}
xtext {
                version = '2.17.1'
                languages {
                    xtend {
                        setup = 'org.eclipse.xtend.core.XtendStandaloneSetup'
                        generator.outlet.producesJava = true
                    }
                }
                
                
    }


tasks.withType(org.xtext.gradle.tasks.XtextGenerate) {
    bootstrapClasspath = configurations.compileClasspath
    classesDirs = sourceSets.main.output.classesDirs
    languages = [xtext.languages.xtend]
    sourceSetOutputs = sourceSets.main.xtend.output
    sources = sourceSets.main.xtend
}


Errors image:


What are the errors?

@SimonJacobs - Java source code is not being generated for xtend source files, and generateXtext task is getting failed. Error image i have attached in the description.

@SimonJacobs - If you feel that my build.gradle script was wrong, then please suggest me how to apply xtend plugin and build xtend source code with gradle.

Your error message suggests an incompatibility between the version of the Xtext plugins (2.0.6) and the version of Gradle (7.3.3) you are using.
The latest version of the Xtext plugins is 4.0.0. I suggest you upgrade to that version or, if there is a reason you must use an older version, downgrade Gradle. A quick look at past Gradle releases suggests that that error might have been introduced in version 4.0 of Gradle, so you should try Gradle versions before that.
